# Scrapy Puppeteer ans recaptcha v2

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website

```
 def start_requests(self):
        yield PuppeteerRequest(
            'https://www.website.es/xxx/yyy/121111',
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

but I a land in a captcha page, with checkbox I am not a robot.
Is there a way to solve it without calling any third parties ?
Maybe by using this: https://github.com/dessant/buster

Comment: it depends on what technology the website uses to detect automated requests

Comment: @wishmaster its www.ticketmaster.com

Comment: Where does `PuppeteerRequest` come from? Are you or the Scrapy extension you are using doing anything to remove stuff from your headless browser that identifies it as a headless browser? Are you using plugins?

Comment: @Gallaecio the website is protected by distil networks

Comment: @Baku the website has an API for developers, you should use it instead